# TomEE vs Apache Geronimo

Tags: java, java-ee, tomee, geronimo

Поясните, пожалуйста, чем отличаются продукты TomEE и Apache Geronimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И то и другое - реализации J2EE стека (сервера приложений) на базе Tomcat. Различия - в наборе используемых компонент, и в том факте, что Geronimo скорее мертв, чем жив (последний релиз - в 2013м году), а TomEE активно развивается, поддерживается, и на подходе версия для J2EE 7.

```
|                   | Apache TomEE                | Apache Geronimo                       |
|-------------------|-----------------------------|---------------------------------------|
| Сервлет-контейнер | Apache Tomcat               | Apache Tomcat | Jetty                 |
| EJB               | Apache OpenEJB              | Apache OpenEJB                        |
| CDI               | Apache OpenWebBeans         |                                       |
| JPA               | Apache OpenJPA              | Apache OpenJPA                        |
| JTA               | Apache Geronimo Transaction |                                       |
| JSF               | Apache MyFaces              |                                       |
| JMS               | Apache ActiveMQ             | Apache ActiveMQ                       |
| Web Services      | Apache CXF                  | Apache Axis, Apache Scout, Apache CXF |
| RDBMS             | Apache Derby                | Apache Derby                          |
| ESB               |                             | Apache ServiceMix                     |
| Clustering        |                             | Apache WADI                           |
```